# Pull Account Information Into Case Using VF Controller

Tags: visualforce, case

I am overriding my New Case button with a VF page.  I am trying to pre-populate fields on cases created with a certain record type with values from the Account, but I'm not sure how to pull them into the controller.  Can anyone help?

```
//Controller to Override Case creation to allow for Account Services VF pages but maintain standard pgs for all other cases
public with sharing class VF_Controller_CaseAcctSvcsNew{

public Case c1;

    public VF_Controller_CaseAcctSvcsNew(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.c1 = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    }


    public PageReference CaseRedirect() {
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == '012L0000000DPwQ'){
            DateTime d = Date.Today();
            c1.OwnerId='00GL0000001SUhm';
            c1.Case_Reason__c = 'Screenshot';
            c1.Due_Date_AcctSvcs__c = System.now() + 24;
            c1.Region__c = Account.Region__c;
            c1.Subject = 'Screenshot Request for ' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId') + ' ' + d.format('MM/dd/yyyy');
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/VF_AcctSvcsNew');
            return pageRef;
        }
        else if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId') == null){
            PageReference pageRef2 = new PageReference('https://cs8.salesforce.com/500/e?RecordType='+c1.RecordTypeId+'&ent=Case&nooverride=1');
            return pageRef2;
        }
        else{
            PageReference pageRef3 = new PageReference('https://cs8.salesforce.com/500/e?def_account_id='+c1.AccountId+'&RecordType='+c1.RecordTypeId+'&ent=Case&nooverride=1');
            return pageRef3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are creating case in vf page, you would have to monitor the selection of account and once user selects it, make some ajax calls using visualforce action tags, to get the account fields and then display them back

Comment: @Asif -- Thanks.  Do you have some examples of code that does that?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm ----- This link has example code which can get you started